# rotate image on horizontal scroll

Tags: css, scroll, rotation, webkit-transform

I'm using this code for letting a image rotate on scroll, and it's working great:

```
    <script>
$(window).scroll(function() {
var theta = $(window).scrollTop() % Math.PI;
$('#leftgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + theta + 'rad)' });
$('#rightgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(-' + theta + 'rad)' });
});
</script>
```

Instead of .scrollTop, I use .scrollLeft because my site is horizontally scrolling. I got this code from: http://demosthenes.info/blog/718/Rotating-Elements-With-Page-Scroll-In-JQuery

The example on this site has 2 images. They are turning in opposite directions and with different speed. How can I achieve this? I looked in de source of the demo site and noticed -webkit-transform. I guess this has to do with it? Can someone help?

I want my image to turn the other side and I want it to turn at slower speed.

Answer (score 0):

Very simply, just apply a different transform to each element. In the example you give, you have the `#rightgear` element rotate `-theta` rads while the `#leftgear` element rotates `theta` rads. You can apply a small modifier to one of these to change the speed, like:

```
<script>
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var theta = $(window).scrollTop() % Math.PI;
        $('#leftgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + theta + 'rad)' });
        $('#rightgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(-' + theta + 'rad)' });
        $('#slowgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + 0.25*theta + 'rad)' });
        $('#fastgear').css({ transform: 'rotate(' + 10*theta + 'rad)' });
    });
</script>
```